# Time machine clean up hangs chrome (and other apps)

Tags: time-machine, google-chrome

Whenever Time Machine finishes a backup and says its "Cleaning up" other applications start to hang until its finished - worst of which is Chrome - Chrome won't open a new URL until Time Machine is done.

Today this happened after Time Machine backed up only 65 kb of changed files - after that tiny backup it spent 5 minutes cleaning up. Very frustrating.

I'm assuming Time Machine is locking files somewhere that chrome is waiting on. But I can't find mention of this behaviour by googling.

Is there any work around available short of ditching time machine?

I'm on snow leopard, up to date with software updates, time machine is backing up to a USB attached disk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, how to prevent it,
but here is [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15127/49492) how to exclude Chrome files from backup.

If not very important to keep the state of Chrome Browser at a certain moment - it might help.